# xpath: filter selected nodes based on type of parent node

Tags: xpath

Here's a sample of the XML I'm dealing with:

```
<subchapter>
    <section>
    </section>
</subchapter>
<part>
    <section>
    </section>
</part>
<part>
    <section>
    </section>
</part>
<quotedContent>
    <section>
    </section>
</quotedContent>
```

I'm trying to filter out certain nodes based on the type of their parents nodes. In other words, I want to find all the `<section>` nodes NOT in `<quotedContent>` nodes. There are various other parent nodes in addition to `<part>` and `<subchapter>` that I want to be included in my end result. So, it's a matter of excluding just the `<quotedContent>` nodes.  I'm pretty sure its just a matter of getting the xpath string correct.

I'm using R's xml2 package, specifically the xml_find_all() function, as follows:

```r
xml_find_all(ustc, "..//d1:section[parent='part']", ns = xml_ns(ustc))
```

Based on the above xml example, I would expect to get two  nodes -- the first two, not the last one inside the .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `not(parent::quotedContent)` in the predicate e.g. `//section[not(parent::quotedContent)]`. Or `//*[not(self::quotedContent)]/section`.

Comment: Thanks a million, @Martin Honnen. That worked.  My final xpath string was `//d1:section[not(parent::d1:quotedContent)]`